# New-mailboxrestorerequest fails with MapiExceptionInvalidParameter: Unable to modify table. Howzat?

Tags: windows, exchange-2010

I have been having quite a bit of trouble copying a mailbox from a recovery database to a user.

Things I tried:
- restoring to a different mailbox  (this got me further than 10% for some reason)
- clearing the mailbox restore queue
- resuming the mailbox restore request
- putting it on a different store (with no size limits)
- Taking the recovery database offline and running eseutil using repair mode.
- I also tried to use MFCMAPI (per instructions in http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdeploylegacy/thread/dab69357-a24b-456b-8c54-e854f61b415d/) but I get a permissions error even when I run it as an exchange administrator - not sure about that one.

ANY suggestions someone might be able to offer would be most welcome.
Thank you thank you thank you - this one is driving me a little nuts!

This is the error text I get:

```
                                    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropExtendedError [250]
                                    Lid: 1494    ---- Remote Context Beg ----
                                    Lid: 26426   ROP: ropModifyRules [65]
                                    Lid: 23921   StoreEc: 0x3EC
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x668F0040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x668F0040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 48851
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 51077   dwParam: 0x80000000
                                    Lid: 65267
                                    Lid: 40691
                                    Lid: 5559    StoreEc: 0x80070057
                                    Lid: 65015
                                    Lid: 65439
                                    Lid: 4302    StoreEc: 0x80070057
                                    Lid: 1750    ---- Remote Context End ----
                                    Lid: 26849
                                    Lid: 21817   ROP Failure: 0x80070057
                                    Lid: 29150
                                    Lid: 20446   StoreEc: 0x80070057
    FailureTimestamp              : 4/30/2013 10:23:12 AM
                                Operation: IDestinationFolder.SetRules
                                OperationSide: Target
                                Primary (1659f8dd-27de-4516-a019-a6fb06700c0e)
                                Rules: [Rule: Condition: Restriction: AND[OR[OR[]; AND[OR[AND[EXIST[ptag:SpamConfidence
                                Level]; PROPERTY[ptag:SpamConfidenceLevel, GreaterThan, val:[Tag:SpamConfidenceLevel, V
                                alue:-1(int)]]]; OR[]]; NOT[OR[OR[]; RECIPIENT[OR[]]]]]]; NOT[OR[OR[CONTENT[ptag:Sender
                                EmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX
                                -news.com"(string)]]]; RECIPIENT[OR[]]; OR[CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase,
                                 val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:Sende
                                rEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(st
                                ring)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Valu
                                e:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:S
                                enderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress,
                                 IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CON
                                TENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEm
                                ailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddre
                                ss, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONT
                                ENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:Sender
                                EmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, I
                                gnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT
                                [ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAdd
                                ress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCa
                                se, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:
                                SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress,
                                 Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase
                                , val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:Send
                                erEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress,
                                 Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[
                                Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmai
                                lAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string
                                )]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase,
                                 val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:Sender
                                EmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(st
                                ring)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Valu
                                e:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag
                                :SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderE
                                mailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string
                                )]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:
                                SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailA
                                ddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]];
                                CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailA
                                ddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, Ignor
                                eCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag
                                :SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"
                                (string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, V
                                alue:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, va
                                l:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]]]]]; Actions: [RuleAc
                                tion: MOVE FolderEID:[len=46, data=000000001B430F07B915DC4FA5F6DB8EE47029AD01007CE4C91B
                                646B3A4CBF3F575F6125703C00000051E8480000], StoreEID:[len=363, data=0000000038A1BB1005E5
                                101AA1BB08002B2A56C20000454D534D44422E444C4C00000000000000001B55FA20AA6611CD9BC800AA002
                                FC45A0C0000004952495332303033002F6F3D4C7574686572616E20536F6369616C20536572766963657320
                                6F6620574920616E64205570706572204D6963686967616E2F6F753D46697273742041646D696E697374726
                                1746976652047726F75702F636E3D526563697069656E74732F636E3D4256656C67757468323800D83521F3
                                B700000001000000140000008F0000002F6F3D4C7574686572616E20536F6369616C2053657276696365732
                                06F6620574920616E64205570706572204D6963686967616E2F6F753D46697273742041646D696E69737472
                                61746976652047726F75702F636E3D436F6E66696775726174696F6E2F636E3D536572766572732F636E3D4
                                95249533230303300690072006900730032003000300033002E006C00730073002E006C006F00630061006C
                                0000000000]; RuleAction: TAG [Tag:0x81400003(NamedProp), Value:-281185362(int)]]; Name
                                'Junk E-mail Rule'; Provider: 'JunkEmailRule'; ProviderData: 01000000000000008177B9A39D
                                65E340; ExecutionSequence: 0; Level: 0; StateFlags: 49; UserFlags: 0; IsExtended: True;
                                 Rule: Condition: none; Actions: [RuleAction: OOFREPLY TemplateEID:null, TemplateGuid:e
                                2bfeefd-ab3e-4d0d-801f-2680c1c6c67f, Flags:0]; Name ''; Provider: 'MSFT:TDX OOF Rules';
                                 ProviderData: ; ExecutionSequence: 50; Level: 0; StateFlags: 141; UserFlags: 2; IsExte
                                nded: False]
                                --------
                                Folder: '/Top of Information Store/Inbox', entryId [len=46, data=00000000202AD623D869B9
                                49BFE92A4FCC3134BB0100DB0B62EE3573BA42841E548A53B58C3300000125B5030000], parentId [len=
                                46, data=00000000202AD623D869B949BFE92A4FCC3134BB0100DB0B62EE3573BA42841E548A53B58C3300
                                000125B5000000]
IsValid                       : True
ValidationMessage             :
OrganizationId                :
RequestGuid                   : ead8a743-d2fc-441b-95f9-99b334b33bc2
RequestQueue                  : VIP Large Store 1
Identity                      : RequestGuid (ead8a743-d2fc-441b-95f9-99b334b33bc2), RequestQueue: (545ddb8e-c471-4f56-8
                                7d9-a09faec068ab)
Report                        : 4/30/2013 10:17:12 AM [mailstore1] 'lss.local/Administrators/Dan Gapinski' created requ
                                est.
                                4/30/2013 10:17:12 AM [mailstore1] 'lss.local/Administrators/Dan Gapinski' allowed the
                                request to be created with mismatching source and target mailboxes.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:20 AM [mailtransport] The Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Replication servic
                                e 'mailtransport.lss.local' (14.2.247.1 caps:07) is examining the request.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:20 AM [mailtransport] Connected to source mailbox 'Restore (9c88f373-90
                                d0-40b3-af12-4d5a09454b16)', database 'RDB', Mailbox server 'MAILSTORE1.lss.local' Vers
                                ion 14.2 (Build 247.0).
                                4/30/2013 10:18:20 AM [mailtransport] Connected to target mailbox 'Primary (1659f8dd-27
                                de-4516-a019-a6fb06700c0e)', database 'VIP Large Store 1', Mailbox server 'MAILSTORE2.l
                                ss.local' Version 14.2 (Build 247.0).
                                4/30/2013 10:18:20 AM [mailtransport] Request processing started.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:20 AM [mailtransport] Stage: CreatingFolderHierarchy. Percent complete:
                                 5.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:21 AM [mailtransport] Merge initialized for mailbox 'Primary (1659f8dd-
                                27de-4516-a019-a6fb06700c0e)': 32 folders total. Estimated data size: 9904 items, 1.149
                                 GB (1,233,737,824 bytes).
                                4/30/2013 10:18:21 AM [mailtransport] Stage: CopyingMessages. Percent complete: 10.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:21 AM [mailtransport] Copy progress: 0/9904 messages, 0 B (0 bytes)/1.1
                                49 GB (1,233,737,824 bytes).
                                4/30/2013 10:18:21 AM [mailtransport] Merging folder '/Top of Information Store/Contact
                                s [Contacts]' into '/Top of Information Store/Contacts [Contacts]'.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:21 AM [mailtransport] Copying 312 items, 236.4 KB (242,024 bytes). Skip
                                ping 3 items, 696 B (696 bytes).
                                4/30/2013 10:18:23 AM [mailtransport] Stage: CopyingMessages. Percent complete: 10.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:23 AM [mailtransport] Copy progress: 100/9901 messages, 81.49 KB (83,45
                                0 bytes)/1.149 GB (1,233,736,432 bytes).
                                4/30/2013 10:18:26 AM [mailtransport] Merging folder '/Top of Information Store/Calenda
                                r [Calendar]' into '/Top of Information Store/Calendar [Calendar]'.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:26 AM [mailtransport] Copying 259 items, 5.33 MB (5,589,060 bytes). Ski
                                pping 7 items, 12.26 KB (12,558 bytes).
                                4/30/2013 10:18:33 AM [mailtransport] Merging folder '/Top of Information Store/Tasks [
                                Tasks]' into '/Top of Information Store/Tasks [Tasks]'.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:33 AM [mailtransport] Copying 3 items, 2.586 KB (2,648 bytes). Skipping
                                 1 items, 144 B (144 bytes).
                                4/30/2013 10:18:33 AM [mailtransport] Merging folder '/Top of Information Store/Notes [
                                Notes]' into '/Top of Information Store/Notes [Notes]'.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:33 AM [mailtransport] Copying 1 items, 738 B (738 bytes). Skipping 1 it
                                ems, 144 B (144 bytes).
                                4/30/2013 10:18:33 AM [mailtransport] Merging folder '/Top of Information Store/Inbox [
                                Inbox]' into '/Top of Information Store/Inbox [Inbox]'.
                                4/30/2013 10:18:33 AM [mailtransport] Copying 3451 items, 586.3 MB (614,733,455 bytes).
                                 Skipping 14 items, 228.5 KB (234,026 bytes).
                                4/30/2013 10:23:12 AM [mailtransport] Fatal error MapiExceptionInvalidParameter has occ
                                urred.
                                Error details: MapiExceptionInvalidParameter: Unable to modify table. (hr=0x80070057, e
                                c=-2147024809)
                                Diagnostic context:
                                    Lid: 55847   EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolSessionDoRpc called [length=192]
                                    Lid: 43559   EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolSessionDoRpc returned [ec=0x0][length=340][latency=15
                                ]
                                    Lid: 23226   --- ROP Parse Start ---
                                    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropModifyRules [65]
                                    Lid: 17082   ROP Error: 0x80070057
                                    Lid: 27745
                                    Lid: 21921   StoreEc: 0x80070057
                                    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropExtendedError [250]
                                    Lid: 1494    ---- Remote Context Beg ----
                                    Lid: 26426   ROP: ropModifyRules [65]
                                    Lid: 23921   StoreEc: 0x3EC
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x668F0040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x668F0040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 48851
                                    Lid: 21970   StoreEc: 0x8004010F PropTag: 0x67F60040
                                    Lid: 51077   dwParam: 0x80000000
                                    Lid: 65267
                                    Lid: 40691
                                    Lid: 5559    StoreEc: 0x80070057
                                    Lid: 65015
                                    Lid: 65439
                                    Lid: 4302    StoreEc: 0x80070057
                                    Lid: 1750    ---- Remote Context End ----
                                    Lid: 26849
                                    Lid: 21817   ROP Failure: 0x80070057
                                    Lid: 29150
                                    Lid: 20446   StoreEc: 0x80070057
                                   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32 hresult, Sa
                                feExInterfaceHandle iUnknown, Exception innerException)
                                   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiModifyTable.ModifyTable(ModifyTableFlags flags, ICollection`1
                                rowList)
                                   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiFolder.AddRules(Rule[] rules)
                                   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiFolder.SetRules(Rule[] rules)
                                   at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.LocalDestinationFolder.Microsoft.Exc
                                hange.MailboxReplicationService.IDestinationFolder.SetRules(RuleData[] rules)
                                   at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.DestinationFolderWrapper.<>c__Displa
                                yClass31.<Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.IDestinationFolder.SetRules>b__3
                                0()
                                   at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.ExecutionContext.Execute(GenericCall
                                Delegate operation)
                                   at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.DestinationFolderWrapper.Microsoft.E
                                xchange.MailboxReplicationService.IDestinationFolder.SetRules(RuleData[] rules)
                                   at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.MailboxMerger.CopyFolderData(FolderM
                                apping fm, ISourceFolder srcFolder, IDestinationFolder destFolder)
                                   at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.MergeJob.<>c__DisplayClasse.<CopyFol
                                der>b__d()
                                   at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.ExecutionContext.Execute(GenericCall
                                Delegate operation)
                                   at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.MergeJob.CopyFolder(Object[] wiParam
                                s)
                                   at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.CommonUtils.CatchKnownExceptions(Gen
                                ericCallDelegate del, FailureDelegate failureDelegate)
                                Error context: --------
                                Operation: IDestinationFolder.SetRules
                                OperationSide: Target
                                Primary (1659f8dd-27de-4516-a019-a6fb06700c0e)
                                Rules: [Rule: Condition: Restriction: AND[OR[OR[]; AND[OR[AND[EXIST[ptag:SpamConfidence
                                Level]; PROPERTY[ptag:SpamConfidenceLevel, GreaterThan, val:[Tag:SpamConfidenceLevel, V
                                alue:-1(int)]]]; OR[]]; NOT[OR[OR[]; RECIPIENT[OR[]]]]]]; NOT[OR[OR[CONTENT[ptag:Sender
                                EmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX
                                -news.com"(string)]]]; RECIPIENT[OR[]]; OR[CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase,
                                 val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:Sende
                                rEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(st
                                ring)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Valu
                                e:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:S
                                enderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress,
                                 IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CON
                                TENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEm
                                ailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddre
                                ss, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONT
                                ENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:Sender
                                EmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, I
                                gnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT
                                [ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAdd
                                ress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCa
                                se, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:
                                SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress,
                                 Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase
                                , val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:Send
                                erEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress,
                                 Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[
                                Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmai
                                lAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string
                                )]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase,
                                 val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:Sender
                                EmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(st
                                ring)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Valu
                                e:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag
                                :SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderE
                                mailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string
                                )]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:
                                SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailA
                                ddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]];
                                CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailA
                                ddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, Ignor
                                eCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag
                                :SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"
                                (string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, val:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, V
                                alue:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]; CONTENT[ptag:SenderEmailAddress, IgnoreCase, va
                                l:[Tag:SenderEmailAddress, Value:"XXX@XXX.XXX"(string)]]]]]]; Actions: [RuleAc
                                tion: MOVE FolderEID:[len=46, data=removed]; RuleAction: TAG [Tag:0x81400003(NamedProp), Value:-281185362(int)]]; Name
                                'Junk E-mail Rule'; Provider: 'JunkEmailRule'; ProviderData: 01000000000000008177B9A39D
                                65E340; ExecutionSequence: 0; Level: 0; StateFlags: 49; UserFlags: 0; IsExtended: True;
                                 Rule: Condition: none; Actions: [RuleAction: OOFREPLY TemplateEID:null, TemplateGuid:e
                                2bfeefd-ab3e-4d0d-801f-2680c1c6c67f, Flags:0]; Name ''; Provider: 'MSFT:TDX OOF Rules';
                                 ProviderData: ; ExecutionSequence: 50; Level: 0; StateFlags: 141; UserFlags: 2; IsExte
                                nded: False]
                                --------
                                Folder: '/Top of Information Store/Inbox', entryId [len=46, data=00000000202AD623D869B9
                                49BFE92A4FCC3134BB0100DB0B62EE3573BA42841E548A53B58C3300000125B5030000], parentId [len=
                                46, data=00000000202AD623D869B949BFE92A4FCC3134BB0100DB0B62EE3573BA42841E548A53B58C3300
                                000125B5000000]
                                4/30/2013 10:23:12 AM [mailtransport] Relinquishing job.

----------
```

Comment: I can also say that I can recover a similarly-sized mailbox without a problem. Makes me think that it would be a type of mailbox corruption, but I don't know what else to do with it as I have already run eseutil in repair mode. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Restore-Mailbox instead. I've seen this error using New-MailboxRestoreRequest too.

Edit: I always use New-MailboxRestoreRequest, but have found that when running into this error, Restore-Mailbox works as a fallback. I don't prefer the old cmdlet.

Comment: That worked perfectly - thank you thank you thank you!